# How can I display the button only once?

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing all the user's data to the card component, but I want to remove the card when I click the button, without rendering the button more than one time. Is it possible to achieve that?

The cards are stacked on top of each other.

Thanks in advance!

**This is where I'm getting the data and controlling the button click**

```
const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null)
const [selectedUser, setSlectedUser] = React.useState(0)


const getUsers = async () => {
  try{
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/users')
    setUser(response.data)
    console.log(response.data)
  } 
  catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}

useEffect(()=>{
  getUsers()
}, [])

const handleCardClick = (userId) => {
    setSlectedUser(userId)
}

const handleRemove = () => {
    setUser(user.filter((user)=> user.userId !== selectedUser))
}
```

**And this is where I'm rendering it.**

```
<div>
      {user && user.map(user => (
         <div>
           <Card
             country={user.country}
             name={user.name}
             about={user.about}
             photo={user.photo}
             onClick={() => handleCardClick(user.userId)}/>
          </div>
              ))}
          <button className='btn-cards text-center' onClick={handleRemove}>DELETE</button>
</div>
```

**This is the card component**

```
import React from 'react'

const Card = ({name, about, photo, country}) => {


  return (
    //create a card to display the user's profile
    <div className='bg-white rounded-3xl shadow-lg p-6 mb-4 card'>
        <div className='flex flex-row justify-between'>
            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                <img className='rounded-2xl w-96 h-96 object-cover' src={photo} alt="" />
                <h1 className='text-2xl'>{name}</h1>
                <h1 className='text-xl'>{country}</h1>
                <h2 className='text-xl'>{about}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  )
}

export default Card
```

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean by not rendering the button more than once? Do you want just one button outside cards that can remove any card in the list?

Comment: @OsmanysFuentes-Lombá yes cause now I have a button for each card and I thought it's better to have just one that can control the cards if it's possible.

Comment: Yes it's possible, just add to each card a checkbox or an onClick event handler, save in the state the selected card and when the user cliecks the button the selected card(s) will be removed from the list. Do you need a snippet as an example?

Comment: @OsmanysFuentes-Lombá Yes if you can that would help me a lot! Thank you so much

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state:

```js
// In this stae var you will save the selected user ID
const [selectedUser, setSlectedUser] = useState(0)
```

The handlers:

```js
const handleCardClick = (userId) => {
    setSlectedUser(userId)
}

const handleRemove = () => {
    setUser(user.filter((user)=> user.userId !== selectedUser))
}
```

The card item inside the list:

```js
<Card
    country={user.country}
    name={user.name}
    about={user.about}
    photo={user.photo}
    onClick={() => handleCardClick(user.userId)}/>
```

The button, in whatever place you like:

```js
<button className='btn-cards text-center' onClick={handleRemove}>DELETE</button>
```

By the way your root 'div' in the list needs a key, I suggest to use the user's id: `<div key={user.userId}>`

Card component receiving the onClick method as a props:

```js
const Card = ({name, about, photo, country, onClick}) => {


  return (
    //create a card to display the user's profile
    <div className='bg-white rounded-3xl shadow-lg p-6 mb-4 card' onClick={onClick}>
        <div className='flex flex-row justify-between'>
            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                <img className='rounded-2xl w-96 h-96 object-cover' src={photo} alt="" />
                <h1 className='text-2xl'>{name}</h1>
                <h1 className='text-xl'>{country}</h1>
                <h2 className='text-xl'>{about}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  )
}
```

Comment: When I add the user id manually it works but it doesn't seem to catch the user id on click

Comment: try to run a console.log inside handleCardClik to see what's receiving

Comment: Should it trigger when I click on the card? If yes it's not receiving anything

Comment: Yes should the card click is the trigger. Where the Card component comes from?

Comment: It's inside the components folder of my project

Comment: Update the question with your current code for card list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245368/discussion-between-davide-coppola-and-osmanys-fuentes-lomba).